# Azure AD permissions Framework vs .net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have created two vanilla web applications from the templates.  One Framework and the other .net core.  The .net core one works fine right out of the gates, nothing needed, but the framework site prompts for permission to sign you in and read your profile, see below:

[image]

Why is this?  And does a framework site require the above permission?

Comment: if you have any more query feel free to ask here in this comment.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't think you've answered the actual question though.  Why does .net core not require the same permissions as a framework site.  Can a framework site not need that permission if it's just needing the authentication?

Comment: have you register your application through azure portal? need to have a look on your configuration and setting.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Consent and permissions :**

Azure always care about organizational and user data access on priority. Consent is the process of a user granting authorization to an application to access protected resources on their behalf. An admin or user can be asked for consent to allow access to their organization/individual data.

You can check here more about the [Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) application consent user experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience)

**Permission about Consent framework:**

User is required to consent to the client application first.After consent is given, the client application will be able to call the Microsoft Graph API on behalf of the user. So yes framework site require the above permission.
You can check here more about [Azure Active Directory consent framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework)

Comment: But why doesn't it prompt for .net core apps?  Is this an oversight?

Comment: It has some prerequisite like ; Granting admin consent requires you to sign in as global administrator, an application administrator, or a cloud application administrator.

To restrict access to applications, you need to require user assignment and then assign users or groups to the application. For more information, see Methods for assigning users and groups here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent

Comment: @Herrozerro this resource can also be helpful for dot net core application implementation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2